# Strange behaviour in Rails production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, production-environment, spree

I have a Rails 3 application based on the Spree e-commerce platform. It sends confirmation emails on different events (powered by the state_machine gem) like order placement, order approval, etc. In development mode everything works fine, but in production mode it sends 2 of the same confirmation emails instead of one, and is some cases 4. What can be the cause of it?

Comment: I suggest adding some logging. My favorite is using the `caller` method - http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-caller

Before the email gets sent do `Rails.logger.info caller[0..15].join("\n")` and see if there are multiple calls actually triggering the mail